# VM Instance not enough resources to fufill the request

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

Starting VM instance "xxxxx" failed. Error:

```
The zone 'projects/xxxxxx/zones/us-west2-b' does not 
have enough resources available to fulfill the request. 
Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

I have seen this error message posted before, but all the responses have been that it gets resolved in a few hours. It has been for over a day now. Please let me know if there is any way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Support here!

As you have probably seen in the other questions, there is not that much you can do on your side other than waiting.

We recommend deploying and balancing your workload across multiple zones or regions to reduce the likelihood of an outage. Please review our [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps) which outlines how to build resilient and scalable architectures on Google Cloud Platform.